# Hide shadow on infowindow in Google Map API V3

Tags: google-maps, shadow, infowindow

I want to hide the shadow on infowindow in Google Map API V3. I try to access the Floatshadow pane but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like the InfoBubble library. It's not possible to do this within the API itself.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/

edit: As of v3.11, info windows don't have shadows by default.

Answer (score 13):

```
<style type="text/css">
img[src*="iws3.png"] {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Attach a event listener to your `infoWindow`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(InfoWindow, "domready", function() {   

  setTimeout(function(){$("img[src$='iws3.png']").hide();},80);

});
```