# Hide shadow on Fusion Tables Infowindow in Google Maps v3

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I am trying to hide the infowindow shadow for a Fusion Tables layer infowindow (Google Maps v3).  I've read the thread [Hide shadow on infowindow in Google Map API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166042/hide-shadow-on-infowindow-in-google-map-api-v3) but it the "style" suggestion doesn't seem to have any effect, and I'm not sure how to get the necessary access to the infowindow object itself (although I can access the html through the infoWindowHtml property).

I've read about custom overlays and how to hide the shadow for them, but how do you do this for a non-custom overlay?

The reason I want to do this is because of the IE 7/8 issue described here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2797

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [infobubble utility library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/) (allows you to control the shadow); or write your own infowindow that doesn't have a shadow.

To use the infoBubble library with FusionTablesLayer:

1. set [{suppressInfoWindows:false}](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pl#FusionTablesLayerOptions) - suppresses the default infowindows
2. add a [click listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pl#MapsEventListener) to the FusionTablesLayer
3. in that [click listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pl#FusionTablesMouseEvent), you can access the default InfoWindow HTML (.infoWindowHtml)
4. open the infoBubble with that content (or modify it if you want)

Comment: Thanks.  I can see how this could work for InfoWindows in general, but not for Fusion Table infowindows, where you have less control. It seems that with Fusion Tables you can either get the standard infowindow (with the ability to include your own html) or no infowindow at all (setting suppressInfoWindows to true will disable the click event).

Comment: Sorry, I do this so often, I forget it isn't obvious, see my updated answer.